# Using mocks to test controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, mocking

It is my second day of learning and doing unit testing. and my team uses `NSubstitute`.

Here is the action method I have written and now I have to write some unit tests for it. I don't know how to go about it? Do we mock the `controller`? then do we mock a `GET` method? How ? How do we test if it posted something and was `POST` ? etc...

```
 public ActionResult ForgotPassword(string button, ForgotPasswordViewModel fpModel = null)
    {
        string method = HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod;

        if (method == "GET")
        {
            ViewBag.Status = "CREATE_TASK";
            ForgotPasswordViewModel model = _forgotPasswordManager.LoadForgotPasswordSettings();
            ModelState.Clear();

            if (model != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.ForgotPasswordMethod) && model.ForgotPasswordMethod.Trim().ToUpper() == "TASKS")
                return View(model);
        }

        if (method == "POST")
        {
            // cancel button, go back to LoginPage
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(button) && button == "cancel")
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }
            else
            {
                if (this.CreateTask(fpModel))
                {
                    ViewBag.Status = "TASK_CREATED";
                }
                else
                {
                    fpModel = new ForgotPasswordViewModel();
                    ViewBag.Status = "CREATE_TASK";
                    return View(fpModel);
                }
            }
        }

        return View(fpModel);
    }
```

Comment: Not an expert so won't attempt full answer. No, don't mock the class you are going to test. You mock classes to make pretend implementations of them that can be made available to the method you're testing. If you mock the class you want to test then you're not really testing it. You need to think what it is about the objects used by the method you test that won't work when you run a test and mock those things. For example, will there be a HttpContext when you run a unit test?

Comment: You should take a look at this tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/unit-testing/creating-unit-tests-for-asp-net-mvc-applications-cs